# How to Update common column values from different values in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. My first `table A` contains

```
Tran_Particular | Dr_Tran_Amt | BeneficiaryName | PRNNo
```

columns.

My second table B contains

```
BeneficiaryName | Dr_Tran_Amt | PRNNo
```

columns.

I want to update table `A.PRNNo` but When I am updating this on `BeneficiaryName` and `Dr_Tran_Amt` that time it updates only first value. But In `table B` there are two PRNNO's are exist and In `table A` also two different `Tran_Particular` are exist. I want to update unique PRNNO wrt `Tran_Particular`, `BeneficiaryName` and `Dr_Tran_Amt`.

**Query**.

```
update A
  set a.PRNNo = b.PRNNo
from A a
  inner join B b
    on  a.Dr_Tran_Amt= b.Amount
    and a.BeneficiaryName = b.BeneficiaryName;
```

HoW to update this in SQL server.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Two rows with the same identifying values? How will the database know which value goes with which row? You should join using the primary key (or at least a unique key). What is the primary key of A and B?

Comment: Yes ,two rows with the same indenting values. The problem is I dont have any primary or unique key in my DB. I want update PRNNO in any row first or second.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should get you only the first matching row (the lowest PRNNo value):

```
UPDATE A
  SET a.PRNNo = b.PRNNo
FROM A a
  INNER join B b
    ON  a.Dr_Tran_Amt = b.Amount
    AND a.BeneficiaryName = b.BeneficiaryName
    AND b.PRNNo = (SELECT MIN(c.PRNNo) FROM B c WHERE c.BeneficiaryName = B.BeneficiaryName AND c.Dr_Tran_Amt = b.Dr_Tran_Amt);
```

Comment: This will update only one PRNNO , but how to update the remaining ?

Comment: This updates ALL PRNNo values in table A to the Minimum PRNNo value of Table B where the Dr_Tran_Amt in Table A matches the Amount in Table B, and the BeneficiaryName in Table A matches the BeneficiaryName of Table B.  In your example tables above, both rows 1 and 2 of Table A will have the PRNNo set to 119699228.